# Replacing values in quantitative variables with r software

Tags: r

My question could be simple for some of you. I need to replace the value "0" by "1" from my quanti variable.

I tried this code :

```
Loaloa$NewQuantiVar[Loaloa$OldQuantiVar==0] = 1
summary(Loaloa$NewQuantiVar)
```

But NAs appear for values different from 0.

So, how to keep both replaced and non-replaced values ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, I think :

```
Loaloa$NewQuantiVar=replace(Loaloa$OldQuantiVar,Loaloa$OldQuantiVar <=0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`NewQuantiVar` is probably `factor` variable (Check `class(Loaloa$NewQuantiVar)`). Change it to numeric first and use the above code.

```
Loaloa$NewQuantiVar <- as.numeric(as.character(Loaloa$NewQuantiVar))
Loaloa$NewQuantiVar[Loaloa$OldQuantiVar==0] = 1
```